# Best practices of writing unit tests in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I'm new to AngularJs unit testing, and I can't decide on what's the best strategy when it comes to unit testing my `AngularJs + ASP.NET MVC(C#)` application.

I am looking for a best practices of writing `unit tests in AngularJs`.

I am also looking for a `tools` for same.

> Note : My applications are mostly data centric.

Comment: Did you find my answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

Look no further than the documentation of unit-testing on AngularJS's site: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing.

[QuickLeft](https://quickleft.com/blog/angularjs-unit-testing-for-real-though/), [Smashing Magazine](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/10/introduction-to-unit-testing-in-angularjs/) and [SitePoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/unit-testing-angularjs-services-controllers-providers/) has some good examples of how to unit-test. They all include certain practices used commonly. They all mention tools used as well such as Karma, Protractor etc.